# Python Folium package- is it possible to plot markers on top of a HeatMap?

Tags: python, maps, heatmap, folium

I have added a heatmap to my map and it works correctly.
Using another data set, I want to be able to plot markers on top of the heatmap.
Is it possible to do this? I have read a bit about layers but I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

My code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/fluffy/Documents/uscitiesv1.4.csv')
airports = pd.read_csv('/home/fluffy/Downloads/us-airports.csv')

map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)
# create data frame from the city population dataset
df = df.dropna()
# extract the lat/long for use in heatmap
heatdf = [[row['lat'], row['lng']] for index, row in df.iterrows()]
HeatMap(heatdf, min_opacity = .4).add_to(map)
```

This works for the heatmap.
This does not work for the markers, though it also may be I have some other mistakes as it causes an error saying "'Series' object has no attribute 'as_type'"

```
for i in range(0,len(airports)):
    folium.Marker([data.iloc[i]['lon'], data.iloc[i]['lat']], popup=data.iloc[i]['name']).add_to(map)
```

Before I bang my head against a wall for a long time, is this even possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact thing and the closest I have found is the following -

```
for idx, row in state_geo.iterrows():
    popup = idx
    folium.CircleMarker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], popup=popup,
                        radius=1, color='white').add_to(map)
```

I am not sure if this will help however as I have a similar dataframe with 3 columns - Lat, Long and Value and I wanted my HeatMap to lrovide the user with the value of 'Value' as they hover over the HeatMap.

Very keen to know if this works for you though...

Comment: And if you just want the popup feature without the markers, you can set `opacity=0` instead of `color='white'`.